# Controlling NetLogo with Java errors when asking for patch color?

Tags: java, api, netlogo

For an example, I have NetLogo file toy.nlogo that all it does is when the setup command is performed, all of the patches are set to the color "9" (a light gray). I use the following code to do so, but it continually results in an error:

```
workspace.open("toy.nlogo");
workspace.command("setup");
System.out.println(workspace.report("ask patch 10 10 [show pcolor]"));
workspace.dispose();
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: yeah, I happened to be able to spot the problem without seeing the error message, but in general, Martin is right: never say "an error". Show the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

`ask` is a command, not a reporter. It does not report a value. (Nor does `show`.)

Try changing your third line to:

```
System.out.println(workspace.report("[pcolor] of patch 10 10"));
```